# Recursively passing selectors to dynamically created children to look up Redux store data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I currently have a redux state with a tree like this :

```
state = {
  manager: {
   items: {
    key01: { data: {...}, childrenItems: {...}, childrenKeys: [...] },
    key02: { data: {}, childrenItems: {}, childrenKeys: [] }, ...
    },
  keys: [key02, key01 ...] 
  }...
}
```

Where order is decided by the array of keys. Keys are mapped to and each key is given a Component

```
{keys.map((uniquekey: string) => {
        return <Item uniqueKey={uniquekey} key={uniquekey} />;
  })}
```

And found with a selector of:

```
const item: Manager = useSelector(
(state: AppState) => state.manager.Items[uniqueKey],
shallowEqual
```

);

Each Item has a Node that is Rendered in the Item component and I'd like for it to recursively render its children and respectively have the children look up their own data from unique key its given.

```
{React.cloneElement(
    node,
    {
      ref: itemRef,
      onClick: handleClick,
      style: item.styling,
    },
    Object.keys(item.childrenItems).map((child: any) => {
      return React.createElement(Item, {
        uniqueKey: child,
        childSelector: ?,
      });
    })
  )}
```

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to build out the entire tree of children components yourself? Seems like duplicated behavior of react recursively calling "render" on its virtualDOM to compute what needs to be displayed. You should leverage that mechanism. Solve first the problem of *a* component using the selector to get its data and children keys, etc...

Comment: I'm making a DOM tree builder that allows for editing of individual DOM nodes. I receive a node and I want to be able to edit the children of that dom node dynamically as well which is why I wanted to recursively wrap the childs in my Item comp. I used this selector approach because I was reading  Mark Erikson's blog post [link](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/) on normalizing the state and allowing children to look up their data by key is beneficial than passing the data down. Was this not the right decision? @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is you want to do but if you want to recursively render items and item.children then maybe the following example can help:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;
const {
  Provider,
  useDispatch,
  useSelector,
  connect,
} = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const defaultState = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'one',
      children: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'two',
          children: [{ id: 3, name: 'three' }],
        },
        { id: 4, name: 'four' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'five',
      children: [
        { id: 6, name: 'six' },
        { id: 7, name: 'seven' },
        { id: 8, name: 'eight' },
      ],
    },
  ],
  active: [],
};
const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
const selectActive = (state) => state.active;
const createSelectItemByIdPath = (path) =>
  createSelector([selectItems], (items) =>
    path.reduce(
      (result, pathId) =>
        result.children.find(({ id }) => id === pathId),
      { children: items }
    )
  );
const createSelectIsActive = (id) =>
  createSelector([selectActive], (active) =>
    active.includes(id)
  );
const TOGGLE_IS_ACTIVE = 'TOGGLE_IS_ACTIVE';
const toggleActiveAction = (id) => ({
  type: TOGGLE_IS_ACTIVE,
  payload: id,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === TOGGLE_IS_ACTIVE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      active: createSelectIsActive(payload)(state)
        ? state.active.filter((a) => a !== payload)
        : state.active.concat(payload),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  defaultState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const Item = React.memo(function ItemComponent({
  id,
  parentPath,
  toggleActive,
}) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  const [
    selectItemByIdPath,
    selectIsActive,
    currentPath,
  ] = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      createSelectItemByIdPath(parentPath.concat(id)),
      createSelectIsActive(id),
      parentPath.concat(id),
    ],
    [parentPath, id]
  );
  const item = useSelector(selectItemByIdPath);
  const active = useSelector(selectIsActive);
  return (
    <li>
      <span
        onClick={(e) => toggleActive(e, id)}
        style={{
          cursor: 'pointer',
          color: active ? 'green' : '',
        }}
      >
        {item.name} (rendered: {r.current} times)
      </span>
      {item.children && (
        <ul>
          {item.children.map(({ id }) => (
            <Item
              key={id}
              id={id}
              parentPath={currentPath}
              toggleActive={toggleActive}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const toggleActive = (e, id) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    dispatch(toggleActiveAction(id));
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          parentPath={[]}
          toggleActive={toggleActive}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```